# Solution of a PDE - method of characteristics

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I started the study of PDEs and came across with this example, which I did not fully understand:

$au_{x} + bu_{y} + cu = f(x,y)$, where $u=u(x,y)$ and a,b are constants with  $a^2+b^2 \neq 0 $

Since $(u_{x},u_{y}).(a,b)$ is the derivative of $u(x,y)$ in the direction of (a,b), we can define a coordinate in the direction of (a,b).
So,
$$w=bx-ay$$
$$z=y$$

Supposing $b \neq 0$, we can write $$x = \frac{w+az}{b}$$

Then we define a function $v$ such that $u(x,y)\equiv v(w,z)=u(\frac{w+az}{b},z)$

Now, the book writes $au_{x} + bu_{y}$ in terms of the new coordinates:
$$au_{x}+bu_{y}=a(v_{w}w_{x}+v_{z}z_{x})+b(v_{w}w_{y}+v_{z}z_{y}) $$
But since $u_{x} = u_{w}w_{x}+u_{z}z_{x}$ and $u_{y} = u_{w}w_{y}+u_{z}z_{y}$, this means that $u_{x} = v_{x}$, $u_{y} = v_{y}$.

Now, I know that $u(x,y)\equiv v(w,z)$, but how can I be sure that the equalities above regarding the partial derivatives are true? Because $u$ and $v$ are not be the same function, since they take different parameters and produce the same result.

Comment: There is something wrong with this picture. Suppose you have point $(x^\ast, y^\ast)$ and the point $(w^\ast, z^\ast)$ that corresponds to the first point by coordinate transformation $(x, y) \mapsto (w(x,y), z(x,y))$. It is clear that $v(w^\ast, z^\ast) = v(w(x^\ast, y^\ast), z(x^\ast, y^\ast)) = u(x^\ast, y^\ast)$. If we differentiate equality $v(w(x^\ast, y^\ast), z(x^\ast, y^\ast)) = u(x^\ast, y^\ast)$ by $x$ and $y$ we will get that $u_x = b \cdot v_w$ and $u_y = v_z - a \cdot v_w$. Moving further, this will help establish the canonical form $b\cdot v_z + c\cdot v = \hat{f}(w, z)$.

Comment: But, if we consider equality $u(x^\ast, y^\ast) = v(w(x^\ast, y^\ast), z(x^\ast, y^\ast))$, the sentence "$u_x = v_x$, $u_y = v_y$" of course makes sense and was used in my calculations

Answer (score 0):

Ali

It seems to me that you found out what you defined. I will explain myself. You have defined $v$ precisely so that $v(w,z) = u(x,y)$. Since you do not know $u$ nor $v$ this does not seem a greet improvement. Now, look what they are giving you
$$ au_x + bu_y = v_w(aw_x + bw_y) + v_z(az_x + bz_y)$$
this is something interesting. You know explicit formulas for $w$ and $z$, that give you
$$  w_x = (bx - ay)_x = b, \quad w_y = -a, \quad z_x = 0, \quad z_y = 1$$
so your initial equation may be rewritten as
$$  v_z (w,z) + c v(w,z) = g(w,z)$$
(where I define $g$ so as to obtain $g(w,z) = f(x,y)$).

I hope this few lines allow to proceed further with the exercise. Since I do not know anything else about I can provide no other help.

Regards,
DG